# pronunciations: copy

Tags: pronunciation

> The **copy** machine is broken. ([related audios](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/484) are linked)

The linked audios have three persons’ pronunciation for ‘*copy*.’ Which are the materials for TOEIC test that is consisted of three national pronunciations: American, British, and Australian. But I don’t acknowledge which is which. Can you write their IPA symbols down and say how they pronounce ‘o’ each?

Comment: #1: /ɑ/, #2 /ɒ/, #3: /ɔ/

Comment: Stoney has a better ear than I. I would have said:#1: /ɑ/, #2: /ɒ/, #3: /ɒ/.

Comment: @tunny Thank you so much. If there wasn’t you expert’s comment as is written, I would have thought it would never happen to me to get English vowels rightly. You and Mr. StoneyB’s sayings, even natives can have different hearings, both make me to try to listen again.

Comment: @Listenever Unfortunately, even if we use the same symbols for some vowels it doesn't really mean they are the same. In my opinion 1: American  2. Australian 3. SSBE English. The symbols traditionally used within each transcription system are as given by tunny above. However, this does not mean the #2 and #3 vowel are the same. To understand the difference you really need a *narrow transcription*, because for example, the sound used for the phoneme /ɒ/ in British and Australian accents are different.

Comment: @Listenever BTW I'm taking it on trust that you're correct about there being one of each of those. The 2nd sound Australian to me just on the basis of the vowel in *copy* ...

Comment: @tunny You may very well be right on 2-3. What I actually *feel* as the difference (I tend to 'hear' with my mouth rather than my ears!) is that 3 is rounder and longer than 2, and 2 is what I was taught (by a South African Anglo actor!) was the way to pronounce 'short o' for stage use in the British tradition - so I assigned /ɒ/ to 2 and /ɔ/ to 3.

Comment: @Araucaria I could follow (1) and (3); (2) couldn’t. The reason I can guess from [Australian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_English) phonology and [the comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_phonology) between three nationalities. Australian’s doesn’t pull down as low as RP or American’s /ɑ/ and /ɒ/. So when the o ball struck other position where I didn’t anticipate, I was confused. I need to broaden the zone for o, for not swing and miss the ball.

Comment: None of them are Australian! Australians would call it a photocopier instead. ;)

Comment: @curiousdannii exactly what I was thinking!

Comment: It's photocopier in BrE too. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably not the answer you want, but having taught English in Korea for nearly 6 years and learned a bit about the publishing industry there, I'm going to take a vote that there *isn't* actually an example of three different English accents represented.

Both recording 1 and 2 can pass for standard North American English. 그리고 재생각에는, it's quite possible that the third one is an Aussie who is trying to use a North American-like accent (since that is what is typically expected when teaching English in Asia).

P.S. I used to grade TOEIC. There aren't any questions *about* accents on there. You simply need to be able to understand Aussie, British, and American/Canadian accents.

Comment: I think you're right in principle, but 2 is definitely not an American accent. I think it sounds like an Indian accent, but very close to an English accent. 3 sounds weird, my guess would be that it's someone putting on an Aussie accent rather than an Aussie putting on a different accent.

Comment: #2 as Indian? Interesting. The only reason I'd think not is because of the way the 'n' in 'broken' is pronounced. (Honestly, I thought #2 sounded like a European--French maybe?--aiming for a North American sound.)

As for #3, to be honest, I can rarely tell an Aussie from a Kiwi so if you're from anywhere near there, I'll take your opinion on it. ;)